# Using SQLCMD Mode within SSMS and a SQL script file path, how can I store the result in a temp table?

Tags: path, ssms, temp-tables, sqlcmd

Using SQLCMD Mode **in SSMS** (not the SQLCMD Utility) and a file path to a SQL query script, I would like to store the results into a temp table.

I am aware the following command executes the query from a file path, but not sure how to store the results into a temp table.

```
:setvar path "C:\filepath"
:r $(path)
```